# Rails & Devise: Email Confirmation text field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Rails 3.2 and Devise.  I am wondering if Devise provides an "Email (address) Confirmation" field just like Password Confirmation for the user to type in a Password field and then type in a Password Confirmation field before the website sends out a confirmation email or processes the sign up registration.  If not, must I add a email_confirmation and validate the User model (after rails g devise User)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14):

I haven't found if devise does what you ask (the question is referring to a second :email_confirmation field similar to :password_confirmation, 'confirmable' seems to be solely related to confirmation *links*).  I had to do this as well and I figured out how to do it using builtin active record validation (rails 3.2.8, devise 2.1.2):

1. In your model add `confirmation: true` to your email validation and `:email_confirmation` to `attr_accessible`.
2. In your view add an `:email_confirmation` field.

As an example, in your model (not assuming other validations or attr_accessibles):

```
attr_accessible :email, :email_confirmation
validates :email, confirmation: true
```

which will use the builtin active record 'confirmation' validation (the same as for passwords).  Finally, in your view(s) you'll need to add something like:

```
<div><%= f.label :email_confirmation %>
<%= f.email_field :email_confirmation %></div>
```

There may be a cleaner way but this worked for me.  However, my only experience with devise so far has been when adding it to existing models, I haven't used it when it's generating the models for you (presumably it's mostly the same).

Answer (score 2):

I was faced with the same issue.

**Here's how I solved it**

[From the official RailsGuide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#confirmation)

You should use this helper when you have two text fields that should receive exactly the same content. For example, you may want to confirm an email address or a password. This validation creates a virtual attribute whose name is the name of the field that has to be confirmed with "_confirmation" appended.

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates :email, confirmation: true
end
```

In your view template you could use something like

```
<%= text_field :person, :email %>
<%= text_field :person, :email_confirmation %>
```

This check is performed only if `email_confirmation` is not `nil`. To require confirmation, make sure to add a presence check for the confirmation attribute (we'll take a look at `presence` later on in this guide):

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates :email, confirmation: true
  validates :email_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

There is also a `:case_sensitive` option that you can use to define whether the confirmation constraint will be case sensitive or not. This option defaults to true.

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates :email, confirmation: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

The default error message for this helper is "**doesn't match confirmation**".

From my experimentation, using the [official RailsGuide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#message),

If you want to change the confirmation message to say, **Email confirmation must be given correctly**, then use add a **message** option this way:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates :email, confirmation: true
  validates :email_confirmation, presence: { message: "must be given correctly" }
end
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

There are a few minor differences for newer versions of Rails compared to the original answer. Just figured I'd add this in case it helps anyone else.

Add an `attr_accessor` for **email_confirmation** to your model and validate the **email** field against the **email_confirmation** field. Set case_sensitive to false `{ case_sensitive: false }` on the validation unless you have configured the email field to be case sensitive.

`app/models/user.rb`

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :email_confirmation
  validates :email, confirmation: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

Permit **email_confirmation** on the sign up params.

`app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb`

```rb
def configure_sign_up_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:email_confirmation])
end
```

Add the **email_confirmation** field to your sign up form.

`app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'devise/shared/error_messages', resource: resource %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: 'email', required: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email_confirmation %>
    <%= f.email_field :email_confirmation, required: true %>
  </div>

  <!-- other fields -->
<% end %>
```

Answer (score -3):

Assuming you have the gem installed, when you perform this function :

```
rails generate devise:install
```

It will generate your migration file that will contain your email_confirmation stuff that you will need to go in the direction you're referring to. All you have to do is *not* comment it out. Otherwise, I comment out all the other stuff that I don't need.

The module you are referring to is called **confirmable**

Assuming you havn't found this yet, this link will explain the rest :

[How do I set up email confirmation with Devise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186584/how-do-i-set-up-email-confirmation-with-devise)

Comment: This does not answer his question.  He is looking for an :email_confirmation field in the signup form that works just like the :password_confirmation field.

Comment: This answer is incorrect I'm afraid; the 'confirmable' module sends emails that require the user to click a link to confirm the account before it can be used, which the questioner is asking if it is possible to automatically add a second email field that must match the first for validation to pass.