# Rails 4 with MailCatcher and Devise gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an app with gem Devise. I need to confirm registration by email. In **config/environment.rb** I added this

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
   :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
   :port => 587,
   :domain => "gmail.com",
   :authentication => 'plain',
   :user_name => "myappname@gmail.com",
   :password => "mypassword"
}
```

In **config/environment/development.rb** added:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { :address => "127.0.0.1", :port => 1025 }
```

I want to catch all email by **gem MailCatcher**
But when i submit to send confirmation instructions nothing happens in mailcatcher gem. But in console i have something like that:

```
Sent mail to abc@mail.ru (3757.4ms)
Date: Thu, 21 Nov 2013 01:19:45 +0400
From: metahall.app@egmail.com
Reply-To: metahall.app@egmail.com
To: abc@mail.ru
Message-ID: <528d2771ac762_27b352e85246162c@Active-pc.mail>
Subject: Confirmation instructions
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Welcome abc@mail.ru!</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><a href="http://localhost:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=hnrgdXgv4nARwiAzaXFy">Confirm my account</a></p>

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
Completed 302 Found in 4648ms (ActiveRecord: 59.8ms)
```

And have NOTHING in mailcathcer. What's wrong?

Comment: What happens if you remove those settings you added to `config/environment.rb`? You shouldn't need those.

Comment: @Ashitaka, thanks. After removing configs from config/environment.rb mailcatcher began to work.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening to me too. I followed these awnser [How do I set up email confirmation with Devise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186584/how-do-i-set-up-email-confirmation-with-devise). Turn out that I forgot to uncomment the `confirmation_token` foreign key in the devise migration. After that, I drop and recreate the database and worked fine!

So, when you generate the devise model, it's create the following migration, with the respective scope.

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.inet     :current_sign_in_ip
      t.inet     :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

To active the confirmation feature, you have to uncomment the following blocks:

```
 ## Confirmable
 t.string   :confirmation_token
 t.datetime :confirmed_at
 t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
 t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable
```

and

```
add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
```

This should make e-mails appears in MailCatcher.

Best luck :)