# Regarding rails4-mongoid-devise

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I developed an application using rails4 mongoid and devise by following the instructions at http://railsapps.github.io/tutorial-rails-mongoid-devise.html. Application is running successfully except confirmation mail and password reset instruction mail features. In my app logs it is showing something like:

```
 Sent mail to csecse.great@gmail.com (8.4ms)
 Date: Wed, 11 Dec 2013 13:56:39 +0530
 From: sender@mail.com
 Reply-To: sender@mail.com
 To: csecse.great@gmail.com
 Message-ID: <52a821bf82f6c_b1f3fc131e38fa07856e@TEST.local.mail>
 Subject: Reset password instructions
 Mime-Version: 1.0
 Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

I am getting this in logs whenever I am requesting for send password instructions but mail is not arriving to my mail id. please suggest me a solution for this.

Comment: You need to show more code for anyone to properly help you. Can you add your config code for the environment you're trying this in?

Comment: This is an old post from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186584/how-do-i-set-up-email-confirmation-with-devise