# How do I generate a random 4-6 digit OTP number to verify email for sign_up in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As we know, I can use several gems to implement OTP but I'm fresher so I want to know, what is the procedure to set an otp for different kind of reason.

Comment: why you are generating OTP to verify email? why can't you use devise inbuilt way to confirm user's email?

Comment: I'm fresher rails developer and I already use devise but I want to know how to verify email. When an user visit for sign up on website.

Comment: https://www.bogotobogo.com/RubyOnRails/RubyOnRails_Devise_Authentication_Sending_Confirmation_Email.php and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186584/how-do-i-set-up-email-confirmation-with-devise

Answer (score 0):

OTP can be used for the MFA authentication.
You can create the OTP by using a ruby random number and can also pass the length of the number.
This can be verified by clicking the link you will send in your email, which will open a pop-up for the OTP input, and submit will validate.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this code will do the work for you:

```
rand.to_s[2..7]
```